# Unable to add Tables/Views/StoredProcedures through EDMX

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, ado.net-entity-data-model, sybase-asa

I'm using **Visual Studio 2015 & Syabse ASA DB (ver 16.0.0.2222) alongwith EntityFramework 6.1.3**.
I add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model

-> I choose EF Designer from Database

-> Establish a New Connection

-> Select the option to Include information in Connection String

-> Click Next -> Ideally the next window should allow me to add Tables/Views/Procedures but Upon clicking Next the window closes.

You may check this link to understand my issue better (only difference is I'm on Visual Studio 2015 & the DB I'm using as Sybase ASA)- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4SwhYYAzx6I

Has anyone come across this kind of problem or know how to fix this?
Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the solution & posting it so that it may help others.

What I already had done?

1. Install the latest developer edition from Sybase
2. Use command prompt with admin priviliges.
3. Naviagte to the path where SQL Anywhere (Sybase ASA) is installed containing the DLL's (in my case: C:/ProgramFiles/SQL Anywhere 16/Assemble/V4)
4. Execute SetupVsPackage.Exe -i -v 6
5. Update app.config file to match the latest provider.
6. Install EntityFramework 6.1.3 to the project where I would add EDMX file.

What I missed?

1. After step 4 above I had to run an additional command -

**Execute SetupVsPackage.Exe -i -v EF6** ***(EF in caps)***

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the connector for avoid this.
You can try this:

- Download the "Get a Free "Developer" Edition" here: http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/oltp-db
- Choose Custom Install when installing.
- Only install the .Net ADO package from the custom install.
- Reference the Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient.dll in your solution from where the install put the files on your drive.

After that you should be able to perform queries, updates etc. in your solution.

Read this if needed: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sdk_12.5.1.adonet/html/adonet/DAFJEFIF.htm

Hope this help.

Comment: I'm using ASA (Adative Server Anywhere - ver 16.0.0.2222), not ASE (Adaptive Server Enterprise).

Comment: IMO you can try to do the same downloading Sap sql anywhere developer edition and searching for an asaclient.dll

Comment: I couldnt do this becuase I couldn't find the aforementioned dll. But before I could dig that further I stumbled upon a solution. Posting it as an answer.